# Uncaught Error: Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode(): Argument #3 ($headers) cannot be passed by reference

Tags: php, jwt

I'm trying to use [JWT library from Firebase in PHP](https://github.com/jcubic/php-terminal-jwt). This is my code:

```php
$env = parse_ini_file('.env');

class Auth {
    private $service;
    public function __construct($service) {
        $this->service = $service;
    }
    public function login($user, $password) {
        global $env;
        if ($user != $env['user'] || $password != $env['password']) {
            return null;
        }
        
        $date = new DateTimeImmutable();
        $expire_at = $date->modify('+6 minutes')->getTimestamp();
        $payload = [
            'iat'  => $date->getTimestamp(),
            'iss'  => $env['domain'],
            'nbf'  => $date->getTimestamp(),
            'exp'  => $expire_at,
            'userName' => $user,
        ];
        return JWT::encode(
            $payload,
            $env['secret'],
            'HS512'
        );
    }
    private function valid_token($jwt) {
        global $env;
        $token = JWT::decode($jwt, $env['secret'], ['HS512']);
        $now = new DateTimeImmutable();
        return $token->iss == $env['domain'] &&
          $token->nbf > $now->getTimestamp() &&
          $token->exp > $now->getTimestamp();
    }
    public function __call($method, $params) {
        $jwt = array_shift($params);
        if (!$this->valid_token($jwt)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Token");
        }

        if (!in_array($method, $methods)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid method $method");
        }
        
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->service, $method), $params);
    }
}
```

But when I try to decode the JWT I got this exception:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode(): Argument #3 ($headers) cannot be passed by reference in /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/terminal/jwt/service.php:45
Stack trace:
#0 /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/terminal/jwt/service.php(54): Auth->valid_token()
#1 /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/terminal/jwt/json-rpc.php(302): Auth->__call()
#2 /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/terminal/jwt/service.php(73): handle_json_rpc()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/terminal/jwt/service.php on line 45
```

ChatGPT 3.5 suggested to change `['HS512']` into `array(HS512')` which throw the same error.

The code is based on this article: [How to Secure a PHP API Using JWT](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/guest-post/securing-php-api-with-jwt/).

To give you a bit of background I'm trying to use this Auth class as a wrapper for Service object and it all act as JSON-RPC for jQuery Terminal. That out of the box call login function get the token save it in localStorage and pass it to other methods as first argument.

Comment: Assign that array to a variable, and then pass that variable in as the third argument

Comment: @ChrisHaas it was the error on my part the API changed, the README of the library show the proper API. This is common from Firebase to change the API so everything breaks with cryptic errors. I'm leaving this as it may be useful for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article I was reading have probably the old API that changed.

The proper code look like this:

```php
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($key, 'HS256'));

$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($key, 'HS256'), $headers = new stdClass());
```

it can be found in [README of the project](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/).

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to the previous version.

```
composer req firebase/php-jwt:6.5.0
```

They've changed header behavior in version 6.6.0 (2023-06-13)

Comment: That is also an option, but I prefer to have the latest version.